# Not aligned Sympy's nice pritting of division

Tags: python, sympy

I'm trying to nice print some divisions with Sympy but I noticed it didn't display aligned.

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing(use_unicode=True)

sympy.pprint(sympy.Mul(-1, sympy.Pow(-5, -1, evaluate=False), evaluate=False))
# Output:
# -1 
# ───
#  -5  # Note that "-5" is displayed slightly more on the right than "-1".
```

Reason/fix for this?

**EDIT:** I did a lot of reverse-engineering using `inspect.getsource` and `inspect.getsourcefile` but it didn't really help out in the end.

Pretty Printing in Sympy seems to be relying on the *Prettyprinter by Jurjen Bos*.

```
import sympy

from sympy.printing.pretty.stringpict import *

sympy.init_printing(use_unicode=True)

prettyForm("-1")/prettyForm("-5")
# Displays:
# -1
# --
# -5
```

So it does display aligned, but I can't get it to use unicode.

The PrettyPrinter is called from the file `sympy/printing/pretty/pretty.py` in the method `PrettyPrinter._print_Mul` which simply `return prettyForm.__mul__(*a)/prettyForm.__mul__(*b)` with, I thought, `a` and `b` simply being `['-1']` and `['-5']` but it wouldn't work.

Comment: I confirm this behaviour. It seems to occur when both numerator and denominator are negative single-digit values.

Comment: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/9450

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found out where the weird part is coming from:

`stringpict.py` line 417:

```
        if num.binding==prettyForm.NEG:
            num = num.right(" ")[0]
```

This is being done ONLY for the numerator. It adds a space after the numerator if the numerator is negative… Weird!

I'm not sure if there can be a fixed other than directly editing the file. I'm going to report this on Github.

Thanks all for your help and suggestion.

**PS:** In the end, I used `pdb` to help me debug and figure out what was actually going out!

**EDIT:** Hotfix if you can't / don't want to edit the code source:

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing(use_unicode=True)

from sympy.printing.pretty.stringpict import prettyForm, stringPict

def newDiv(self, den, slashed=False):
    if slashed:
        raise NotImplementedError("Can't do slashed fraction yet")
    num = self
    if num.binding == prettyForm.DIV:
        num = stringPict(*num.parens())
    if den.binding == prettyForm.DIV:
        den = stringPict(*den.parens())

    return prettyForm(binding=prettyForm.DIV, *stringPict.stack(
        num,
        stringPict.LINE,
        den))

prettyForm.__div__ = newDiv

sympy.pprint(sympy.Mul(-1, sympy.Pow(-5, -1, evaluate=False), evaluate=False))

# Displays properly:
# -1
# ──
# -5
```

I just copied the function from the code source and removed the incriminated line.

Possible improvement could be to `functools.wraps` the new function with the original one.

Answer (score 1):

Negative denominators are not standard and badly handled. If you really need them, you can modify the string outpout given by the pretty function :

```
import sympy
sympy.init_printing(use_unicode=True)
def ppprint(expr):
    p=sympy.pretty(expr)
    s=p.split('\n')
    if len(s)==3 and int(s[2])<0:
        s[0]=" "+s[0]
        s[1]=s[1][0]+s[1]
        p2="\n".join(s)
        print(p2) 
    else: print(p)
```

This extend the bar and the numerator of one unit for negative denominators. No warranty of robustness on big expressions.

```
>>>> ppprint(sympy.Mul(sympy.Pow(-5, -1,evaluate=False),-1,evaluate=False))
 -1 
────
 -5
```

Comment: "Dirty" hack but, that's a (great) start!, I think we could even try to make it more "clever" by approximating both parts' size and try to adjust if we really need to.

Answer (score 0):

I was not quite sure what you are searching for, but I think I was dealing with something similar a while ago.
I got a comprehension list and used this for printing. 
You may find it useful.

```python
    x =  amp * np.sin( 2 * np.pi * 200 * times            ) + nse1
    x2 = np.array_split(x,epochs(
    Rxy[i], freqs_xy = mlab.csd(x2[i], y2[i], NFFT=nfft, Fs=sfreq)
    Rxy_mean0 = [complex(sum(x)/len(x)) for x in Rxy]
    import pprint
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    pp.pprint(Rxy_mean0)
```